# The formula of $E_{16}, E_{18}, E_{20}$ and $E_{22}$ where $E$ is Eisenstein Series.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

There are the formula of $E_{2k}$ for $1 \le k \le 7$ in this link (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinSeries.html).

> $E_2 = 1 - 24 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{1}(k)q^{2k},$
>
> $\cdots$
>
> $E_{14} = 1 - 24 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{13}(k)q^{2k}.$

How do we have the formula of $E_{16}, E_{18}, E_{20}$ and $E_{22}$?

Comment: Just as described at your link, by computing more Bernoulli numbers $B_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link you provided says, we have the general form
$$E_{2n}(q) = 1+c_{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_{2n-1}(k)q^{2k}$$
All you want to do is calculate $c_{2n}$ and the link you provided already does this. Your link states that
$$c_{2n} = \frac{-4n}{B_{2n}}$$
Where the denominator is the Bernoulli Numbers. The Bernoulli Numbers are often defined by the (exponential) generating function
$$\frac{1}{e^x-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k \,x^k}{k!}$$
This *can* be used to calculate the series, but as [this link](http://wstein.org/edu/fall05/168/projects/kevin_mcgown/bernproj.pdf) explains you are probably going to have an easier time by manipulating this series. First we multiply both sides above by $e^{x−1}$ and equate coefficients of $x^{k+1}$ to turn the series into:
$$(k+1)B_k = -\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {m+1 \choose i} B_i$$
Now you just have to divide both sides by $k+1$ and you are good. For computational purposes, save all the terms of $B_i$ in an array and find a good algorithm for calculating combinations. Though nothing comes to mind, there might even be a way to calculate $B_{k+1}$ without summing across all of $B_i$ again *(if anyone has good suggestions for this, please comment and I will add to the body of the post)*